# CanvasRenderingContext2D resetTransform and google closure compiler

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, google-closure-compiler

I've stumbled upon a strange behaviour of google closure compiler, ADVANCED mode, and I can't find an explanation: it renames function resetTransform of CanvasRenderingContext2D

since the problem arised in production code I can't copy-paste here, but I've been able to reproduce the problem in a case here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic9l755dvgkkqv7/case.zip?dl=0

the in-clear problematic snippet is:

```
context.resetTransform ()
context.translate ( 0 , canvas.height )
```

which corresponds to the compiler output:

```
c.a();c.translate(0,b.height);
```

if I'm not mistaken, resetTransform should keep its name, just as it happen to the other members of CanvasRenderingContext2D, for instance, to translate.
the browser can't find the "a" function and generates "TypeError: c.a is not a function"

"c" is effectively an instance of CanvasRenderingContext2D, in fact, if I change c.a to c.resetTransform, the script works perfectly.

what am I doing wrong?

found no references about this problem anywhere

currently I'm using the latest compiler version, downloaded from:
  https://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip

java version si 1.7.0_80, but the problem persists even with an older one

Comment: BTW, you should probably tag this as a "javascript" question, not "java" (of course closure-compiler is written in java but your question is about javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resetTransform` is marked as an [experimental feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/resetTransform) on mozilla.org which explains why it is not yet present in [`closure_compiler/externs/browser/html5.js`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/browser/html5.js).  Closure-compiler therefore doesn't know to not minify that name.

If you can [build closure-compiler from source](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) (its pretty easy to do) then you could add to `html5.js` something like

```
/**
 * @return {undefined}
 */
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform = function() {};
```

and then rebuild the compiler. IIRC, the compiler must be rebuilt for changes to the externs files to have any effect.

You could also submit an issue or pull request at https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/ with the added API.

There might be a way to call `resetTransform` without it being minified in advanced-compile mode.  Closure-compiler won't minify properties accessed by square brackets.

```
(/** Function */mycontext['resetTransform'])();
```

I've never tried this, but I think this would work. The exact expression to make closure-compiler happy with the syntax might need some tweaking.

---

The [instructions for building closure-compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) are a little screwed up at the moment. Here are some basic instructions:

Get a local copy of the closure-compiler repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/closure-compiler.git
```

Later on you can update your copy as needed with

```
git pull
```

build with

```
ant clean
ant jar
```

Check version with:

```
java -jar build/compiler.jar --version
```

Comment: You can also just include an externs file with the definition locally

Comment: Or submit a pull request to the compiler project to add the definition.

Comment: this explains it all: I thought it was becoming obsolete (there's setTransform after all) but found nothing ... for it was the other way around. thanks !